# Getting a <table> from a website using Selenium and casting its data into a Datatable (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, selenium, datatable

I want to get Data (Rows and Colums from a Table and store them in a DataTable (c#)

The table can be found here https://services.gst.gov.in/services/searchtp, add`24AAAFK7189C1ZG` in the GST UIN and then scroll down to click on `SHOW FILING TABLE` to see the table, because its code is very clumsy and big

The table looks like

```
| Financial Year | Tax Period | Date Of Filing | Status |
| 2020-2021      | November   | 18/12/2020     | Filed  |
| 2020-2021      | October    | 12/11/2020     | Filed  |
| 2020-2021      | September  | 18/10/2020     | Filed  |
| 2020-2021      | August     | 18/09/2020     | Filed  |
| 2020-2021      | July       | 18/08/2020     | Filed  |
```

What i want to do is, get all rows from this table and add them into a DataTable and show them in a DataGridView

But I dont really know how to get the data in a DataTable

Thanks

Comment: What government site are you scraping data from? I don't feel confident that you're doing something that is ethical or legal.

Comment: `[YourDataGridView].DataSource = [YourDataTable]`?

Comment: @RyanWilson the site is legal to use, its from the Government Of India, its used to make GST Invoices (A Type of TAX like VAT)

Comment: @Jimi I want help with adding the data from the HTML Table to DataTable, not showing it to a DGV

Comment: First spend time finding if there is a public API with this data before taking on the difficult task of scraping the UI for data.

Comment: @DourHighArch I searched a lot, the API which are available arent free of cost and they arent that flexible. and i am making this open source so anyone else can use it too

Comment: That's all I can give you, I'm not getting an answer from that server :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a representative snippet of the HTML for the table, including all ancestor tags up to the `<body>` tag.